# How to execute 'git comit --amend' in bash script

Tags: bash, git, shell

I'm trying to amend a git commit via a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash 
git commit -as --amend
```

The script stalls waiting for me to enter :wq!

git commit -m "some message" is fine in script, exiting as desired but not for amend.  Can anyone advise on this?

Comment: It created  new commit when tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`--no-edit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---no-edit) flag does just that.

```
git commit -as --amend --no-edit
```

Comment: @John Kugelman we posted simultaneously! I saw you elegantly retracted your answer, but let's note we share the credit here.

Comment: Thank you!  Strange that git commit -h does not show --no-edit as an option.